# How can I dynamically create an ASP:Button that causes no postback inside an UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajax.net

I have a page some 2 ASP Tabs and with an UpdatePanel on the first tab.  Inside the update panel (on page_load), I dynamically create a table that contains rows with cells for an image, some text, and an ASP:Button.  I'd like the button, when clicked to switch tabs from the first to the second.  Instead, all it does is refresh the updatepanel it resides in.  How can I stop it from behaving that way?  How do I get it to perform a function of my own design, instead of posting?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add javascript click event and stop it to do post back by returning false;

In Code behind, where you add button dynamically.

```
btnChangeTab.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return YourJavascriptFunction();");
```

In Client side.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function YourJavascriptFunction()
 {
      //Your javascript code here 
      return false; //the will stop from postback
 }

</script>
```

Comment: That worked beautifully to stop the postback, so + 1 for that man!  however, it seems to not hit the event i attached to it now.  Got this:                         btnViewTasks.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
                        btnViewTasks.Click += new EventHandler(ViewTechnicianTasks);

Comment: Because you stopped it from postback and ViewTechnicianTasks is on server side and needs postback. Now you have to change tab or whatever you want with javascript without going to server.